# How could I define the type of a variable that will be later assigned to an initialized class?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let cached: TYPETOBENAMED | undefined;

export default async function getPackage() {
  if (cached) {
    return cached;
  }

  return import("@package/package_name").then(({ default: AClass }) => {
    cached = new AClass({
      key: apiKey
    });
    return cached;
  });
}
```

I wanted to define `cached` as `unknown | undefined` however that's throwing a ts error `TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'`.

How could I define the type of a variable that will be assigned to an initialized class?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/WYJG2w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: minimal reproducible example would require an apiKey, which is not meant for public eyes.

Comment: Generally to make a [mcve] you should write some new code which exhibits the problem; you shouldn't have to expose any encumbered or private information to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

`let cached: import("@package/package_name").default | undefined;`

Comment: While this may solve your problem, it doesn't explain how, nor would it obviously help others with a similar issue, as it depends on the imported package having an exported type named `default`.  Please consider modifying both the question and the answer so that it is useful for future readers.  Good luck!